# Can I find python modules?

Tags: python, python-module

I found all the other modules in Python33/Lib, but I can't find math . Are they missing or what ? I need to look to the code written by the developers for some reasons ( even if it was written in c ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math`, like many of the core modules, is a built-in.  You'll have to troll through the Python source code.
https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules